# Rows to columns Python Pandas dataframe (pd.melt)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, df, containing transactions by card. One card can have multiple transactions and thus multiple rows. I want to create a new dataframe with one row per card. Problem is that the number of transactions per card can vary. I was under the assumption that the pd.melt could solve this.

dataframe looks like this:

```
CardCode    Coupon  ShopName    TranDate
1028670151  S       ShopA       2018-05-24 21:02:19.000
1028670151  S       ShopB       2018-05-23 13:14:44.000
1028670151  G       ShopC       2018-05-24 12:31:24.000
1029282454  S       ShopA       2018-05-19 19:52:40.000
1029282454  G       ShopB       2018-05-19 14:08:02.000
1029646050  S       ShopD       2018-06-17 14:10:42.000
1029684151  S       ShopE       2018-05-05 12:33:21.000
1029684151  G       ShopB       2018-05-05 15:13:08.000
1029684151  S       ShopC       2018-05-06 14:21:02.000
1029754252  G       ShopA       2018-05-05 10:40:30.000
```

The code I tried:

```
df_new = pd.melt(df, 
                 id_vars = ['CardCode   '], 
                 value_vars = ['TranDate', 'Coupon', 'ShopName'])
```

While this does bring me towards my goal, I don't have a one row per CardCode and that is my ultimate intention here.

Desired output is like this:

```
1028670151  S       ShopA       2018-05-24 21:02:19.000 S       ShopB       2018-05-23 13:14:44.000 G       ShopC       2018-05-24 12:31:24.000
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What would you envisage the row for `CardCode` of "1028670151" looking like? The structure you have now makes sense - I'm not sure you *really* want one row per card. I have a feeling this might be an XY problem and it might help if you described why you want this/what you want to do with that data and something else might be what you're really needing...

Comment: @Jon thanks for your input, I've added desired output.

Comment: So you'd end up with N rows where N is the unique occurrenes of `CardCode` and 3M columns where M is the largest number of transactions for a `CardCode`...? That's a very odd format and will be extremely hard to work with... Can I ask why?

Comment: My customer wants an Excel sheet with one card per row and all it's transactionional info as columns. So CardCode, Coupon_1, ShopName_1, TranDate_1, Coupon_2, Shopname_2, TranDate_2 and so on. Number of columns obviously varies per Card. Does that make my question clear(er) ?

Comment: Ahhh okies... yes... those clients hey... crazy people :)

Comment: Haha, tell me about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you can use `cumcount` and `unstack`:

```
df_out = df.set_index(['CardCode',df.groupby('CardCode').cumcount() + 1])\
           .unstack()\
           .sort_index(level=1, axis=1)

df_out.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i,j in df_out.columns]

df_out = df_out.reset_index()

df_out
```

Output:

```
     CardCode Coupon_1 ShopName_1               TranDate_1 Coupon_2 ShopName_2               TranDate_2 Coupon_3 ShopName_3               TranDate_3
0  1028670151        S      ShopA  2018-05-24 21:02:19.000        S      ShopB  2018-05-23 13:14:44.000        G      ShopC  2018-05-24 12:31:24.000
1  1029282454        S      ShopA  2018-05-19 19:52:40.000        G      ShopB  2018-05-19 14:08:02.000      NaN        NaN                      NaN
2  1029646050        S      ShopD  2018-06-17 14:10:42.000      NaN        NaN                      NaN      NaN        NaN                      NaN
3  1029684151        S      ShopE  2018-05-05 12:33:21.000        G      ShopB  2018-05-05 15:13:08.000        S      ShopC  2018-05-06 14:21:02.000
4  1029754252        G      ShopA  2018-05-05 10:40:30.000      NaN        NaN                      NaN      NaN        NaN                      NaN
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, the syntax is a bit complex for me, but this does work, great!

Comment: @SQL_M Okay run `df.groupby('CardCode').cumcount() + 1` this will give you a running count of distinct CardCode.  Then we use set_index to add the CardCode and the running count.  Next, we unstack the count to put it up in the column headers, this creates a MultiIndex column header.  Then sort the MultiIndex column header by the count level to get all the 1's together then the 2's etc...  The next statement flattens out the multiindex column header into a single level column header using list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks Scott for clearing that up. Kind of an off topic question: Do you know any good resources (tutorials) where I could learn these more advanced topics? There are a lot of tutorials for beginners, but I haven't seen any good topics on, say the level of your answer,

Comment: @SQL_M Ted Petrou book is pretty good on handling real world data.  And, I have learned most of my "advanced" pandas techniques from here on Stack Overflow answering questions.